# Organising java files in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Is there anyway that I can get Android Studio (or a plugin) to organise the contents of my Java files so that it groups properties together, methods group up in an alphabetically order etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, not all things you want but there is a plugin comes with Android Studio which can arrange your code beautifully at some extant .

First you need to set Rules from here(There are some Defaults automatically set in Studio)

```
File > Settings > Code Style > Arrangement
```

[image: arrange code]

Then from opened java file, Go to `Help > Find Action` and start typing `Rearrange code` it will automatically give an action for Arrange your Code .

Shortcut for opening find action `Ctrl+Shift+A`

Comment: Thanks - this is exactly what I wanted.

CTRL + ALT + L (Win/ Linux)
OPTION + CMD + L (Mac)